# How to connect my computer to web hosting MySQL database?

Tags: mysql

I have a software that need connection to a MySQL database to process the data.  I have connected this software with my local computer using XAMPP.  But now I want to connect it to an external database on my web hosting.  When I put the MySQL host and user information in ODBC Connector, it gives error.
Please help me!

Comment: What error message are you getting? Your web host maybe blocking external connections to your MySQL

Comment: This is not a good practice, but you can ask your host to open the port externaly to your database, at least for your IP only

Answer (score 0):

Most web hosters restrict access to their mysql dbs to local connections. So you most likely wont be able to connect from your pc.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. If you know any free web hosting that do not restrict external connection. Please Tell me!